# How Can I Prevent The Suggestion of Custom VBA Functions When Writing Formulas in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am writing a range of VBA functions / subs that can be reused in a number of projects. The issue I have is that these functions are listed in the suggested formula functions when using sheets.

[image]

Making the functions private will prevent this, but what it will also do is remove the handy hints showing the parameters for the functions when called from a module other than where the function is stored.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to prevent the suggestion of custom functions without making them private?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameterless `Public` members of a *standard module* are one of two things:

- `Sub` procedures and they're exposed as *macros*.
- `Function` procedures and they're exposed as UDF's.

Note that members are implicitly `Public` if no access modifier is specified.

A `Sub` that has parameters can't be executed as a *macro*, so it won't show up as an available macro.

A `Function` that has *side-effects* (e.g. mutates some module/global state, or changes other cells' value) is bad code, and a UDF can't change another cell's value anyway.

---

> *Making the functions private will prevent this, but what it will also do is remove the handy hints showing the parameters for the functions when called from a module other than where the function is stored.*

Making it `Private` not only "removes the handy hints", it makes the function inaccessible to other modules, and your code won't compile.

If your code has UDF's, put them all in the same standard module, e.g. `UserFunctions`, and make them explicitly `Public` for readability's sake.

If your code has macros, put them all in the same standard module, e.g. `Macros`, and make them explicitly `Public` for readability's sake.

If your code has functions and procedures that need to be `Public` (e.g. they're accessed from UDF's and/or macros), make them explicitly `Public` for readability's sake, and put them in standard modules named appropriately (i.e. avoid `Helper` and `Manager` modules, they inevitably become a dumping bag of whatever doesn't quite fit anywhere, and grow to a mess).

Then put this at the top:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
```

That option (`Private Module`) prevents all public/exposed members from being picked up as macros and UDF's. `Option Explicit` should just be there anyway.

---

Another way is to implement logic in class modules; members of a class module can't be accessed without an instance of that class (i.e. an object), and therefore won't be exposed as macros/UDF's.

Comment: This works great, I'm hoping you might be able to give some further advice on a new issue. I'm trying to put the reusable functions into an Add-In, and adding this Add-In as a reference (Tools > References) in other add-ins that will use these functions. The issue here is that by implementing your suggestions the private modules are inaccessible to the new Add-In's. Could you add anything further to improve this? Should I create a new question?

Comment: I was going to reply in a comment, but it wouldn't fit - yeah it would probably be better off as a separate question.